# How do I remove a specific line out of a text file?

Tags: python

```py
file = open(userid, "r+") 
#userid is in the form
# A
# B
# C
# etc...
removeRead = file.readlines()
del removeRead[int(index)]
file.write(str(removeRead))
```

This is what I've tried so far. Ive looked at other questions asking this and one of the suggestions was to 'simply iterate over the whole file and write all the lines except the one you want to remove`
with their suggestion being

```py
with open('fordel.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for linenum, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if linenum != badline:
            fo.write(line)
    # obviously not to my code
```

Is this really the simplest solution (i.e does python really not have an inbuilt solution for this?), and how exactly does it work so I can implement it into my code?

Comment: Python is a general purpose programming language, not a text-editing language. This seems short and clear enough. (Arguably, Perl is also a general purpose programming language but can handle this easier, though probably less clearly.)

Comment: If you are open to other solutions, let us know what OS you are using. *nix generally has some convenient utilities available for these kind of problems.

Comment: @00 yeah Im on ubuntu

Comment: `readlines` creates a `list` of lines. Either use `join` to transform the list into a single string if you are going to use `write` or use `writelines`, but `file.write(str(removeRead))` is totally wrong.

Comment: Something like `sed '2d' fordel.txt > out.txt` can do this on the command line. Obvious disadvantages are that the line number is not a variable, and that this is outside of any Python context. But for one-offs (or in shell for loops), this is just one line of sed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you require the `enumerate()` as that is to keep track/count of the number of lines, you could use if you really knew the line at which you want to remove some specific line, but this a maybe simpler variation, give it a shot:

```
  with open("originalfile.txt", "r") as currentfile:
    with open("finalfile.txt", "w") as endfile: 
      for line in currentfile:
        if line.strip("\n") != "the line you want to delete":
           endfile.write(line)
```